# how to overwrite the logo

Tags: javascript, html, django

I want to remove the logo by preview photo on logo [image]
and my script is

```js
        function preview_image(event)
        {
         var reader = new FileReader();
         reader.onload = function()
         {
          var output = document.getElementById('output_image');
          output.src = reader.result;
         }
         reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
        }
```

```html
<label for="id_Photo"><img height="120" width="120" alt="Image description" src="{% static 'images/imglogo.png' %}"></label>
        <input type="file" name="Photo" required="" id="id_Photo" style="display:none" onchange="preview_image(event)">
        <img height="120" width="120" id="output_image"/>
```

Comment: _I want to remove the logo by preview photo on logo_ i don't understand, you don't want preview or you want to overwrite `imglogo.png` ?

Comment: YES I want to overwrite

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<label for="id_Photo"><img  id="output_image" height="120" width="120" alt="Image description" src="{% static 'images/imglogo.png' %}"></label>
            <input type="file" name="Photo" required="" id="id_Photo" style="display:none" onchange="preview_image(event)">
```

instead of

```
<label for="id_Photo"><img height="120" width="120" alt="Image description" src="{% static 'images/imglogo.png' %}"></label>
        <input type="file" name="Photo" required="" id="id_Photo" style="display:none" onchange="preview_image(event)">
        <img height="120" width="120" id="output_image"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the preview image as `output_image` like this

```js
        function preview_image(event)
        {
         var reader = new FileReader();
         reader.onload = function()
         {
          var output = document.getElementById('output_image');
          output.src = reader.result;
         }
         reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
        }
```

```html
<label for="id_Photo"><img height="120" width="120" id="output_image" alt="Image description" src="{% static 'images/imglogo.png' %}"></label>
      <input type="file" name="Photo" required="" id="id_Photo" style="display:none" onchange="preview_image(event)">
```